# How to generate chart on serverside with nodejs?

Tags: node.js, charts, bots, backend

I have a Bot for a personality test. this bot getting(yes/no) answers by asking over 60 questions. after summarizing the results it will give 6 value for indicated indexes. I had to generate a Radar chart with legends and values based on summery and post it back (jpg/png/svg) to user by Bot.

Any one know how can I do that, Any guideline will be helpful.

Comment: Try [Robinhood](https://aurbano.eu/robinhood-node/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [**svg-radar-chart**](https://github.com/derhuerst/svg-radar-chart) package accessible using the NuGet packages.

Comment: This is good but in graphic and adding additional axis seems weak may be I am have not enough try. also for showing value i had to divide them to 10 or 100 to be under 1.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [chartjs-node](https://www.npmjs.com/package/chartjs-node) to generate chart and convert into image in server side in nodejs.